# Why can't I install my distribution into a local copy of python?

Tags: python, powershell, distribution

I've prepared a module that's ready to be uploaded to PyPI, the folder 'nester' has all the necessary components. Equipped with the build, dist, MANIFEST, and the two python files (setup.py and nester.py). Whenever I go to admin PowerShell I try running the final command to download it onto my local python file.

> python.exe setup.py install

it spits back out 'permission denied', am I putting in the wrong command? the textbook I'm working from is working on terminal while I'm on Windows. The aforementioned textbook inputs

> Sudo python3 setup.py install

and it seems to work perfectly for him

[here's what happens every time I try to run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2NqZ.jpg)

Comment: I just ran it on an admin PowerShell and it STILL says permission denied!                                                                                     -                                                                                                                 Day 13, still no answer. Thinking about packing up my bags and livin on the road, maybe there will be a solution out in the road somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This likely happens, as the installer is trying to write into `C:\Program Files` directory. Ordinary user accounts do not have permission to do so, as the error `Access Denied` says.

/In *nix systems, `sudo` is used to act as root, and root can do anything. Thus permissions aren't an issue in the book sample.)

To illustrate your Windows case, see the image below. In the first case, ordinary user is trying to create `test.txt` into `C:\Program Files`. It fails, as expected. The second case does the same, but this time Command Prompt is started with administrative privileges.

As for a fix, you need to run the command in elevated command prompt. The prompt should have window title `Administrator: Command Prompt`, not `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

[image: Trying to write as ordinary and administrator]